# Can't generate webpack-assets.json with webpack-isomorphic-tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-isomorphic-tools

I'm trying to learn React and the whole environment built around it. I do that by trying to construct my own dev-stack.

The problem I can't get across for a very long time is how to serve CSS/Images while not loosing a power of server rendering.

I've read a couple of tutorials and discovered [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools)

I've configured them and managed to get an images supported, sass (transformed to css) as well.

However, I came across an issue that my `webpack-assets.json` file is not generated, instead I see this output. ( [I managed to get it generated on a 2nd run of `npm start` before this commit, but that was definitely not a way to go](https://github.com/jvorcak/universal-react-kit/commit/f5b8baf9bf50231520e843ebd23f6c502a8fab26) , but it showed that the plugin works when a file is present.)

```
$ npm start

> redux-universal-example@0.0.0 start /Users/janvorcak/learning2016
> node src/server/index.js

[webpack-isomorphic-tools] (waiting for the first Webpack build to finish)
[webpack-isomorphic-tools] (waiting for the first Webpack build to finish)
[webpack-isomorphic-tools] (waiting for the first Webpack build to finish)
[webpack-isomorphic-tools] (waiting for the first Webpack build to finish)
```

I understand the purpose of this file, but I can't really figure out why it's not generated at all.

Is there anything that I'm missing?
Here are the relevant files and a repository

- https://github.com/jvorcak/universal-react-kit/tree/sass-loader
  (sass-loader branch on my `universal-react-kit` repository)
- configuration -
  https://github.com/jvorcak/universal-react-kit/blob/sass-loader/webpack-isomorphic-tools-configuration.js
- webpack.config.js -
  https://github.com/jvorcak/universal-react-kit/blob/sass-loader/webpack.config.js
- entry file when running a server https://github.com/jvorcak/universal-react-kit/blob/sass-loader/src/server/index.js

Could somebody please explain what is going on, I've read documentation, blogs, but I'm missing something here. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the assets file is not generated is because you have integrated `webpack-dev-server` into your `server.js`.

https://github.com/jvorcak/universal-react-kit/blob/master/src/server/server.js#L81

That's a wrong way to do it because in production you won't need `webpack-dev-server` and therefore its place is somewhere else.

In your case `webpack-dev-server` is meant to generate `webpack-assets.json` and this `webpack-dev-server` is being run **after** `webpack-isomorphic-tools` `.server()` method calls its callback, but it won't call its callback until it finds `webpack-assets.json`.

The answer is to run your `webpack-dev-server` in a separate process (you may want to refer to github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example for an example of how to achieve that).

https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools/issues/47

You may also like my very own boilerplate which can do all the fancy things

https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webapp

Comment: Thank you, the core of my problem was that I was not running those things in parallel.